# Prove that for any $k \mathbb \in N^*$

Tags: inequality, induction

Prove that for any $k \mathbb \in N^*$: $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(k+1)^3}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {k+1}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k^3}}$$

I have tried to use simple induction but i didn't get a good result

Comment: You could try the Mean Value Theorem…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf would you explain how we can do it with a natural numbers (continuity problem)

Comment: Take $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$ and apply the mean-value theorem to $f(k) - f(k +  1)$.

Comment: Let $f$ be the function defined on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ by $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_+^*,\ f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Then $f$ is continuous on $[k,k+1]$ and differentiable on $(k,k+1)$ hence there exists $c\in(k,k+1)$ such that $f(k+1)-f(k)=f'(c)$…

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{k}}-\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac1{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1})}
$$
and we have 
$$
\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1})\le \sqrt{k+1}\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k+1}) = 2\sqrt{(k+1)^3}$$
and similarly
$$
\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1})\ge \sqrt{k}\sqrt{k}(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k}) = 2\sqrt{k^3}$$
and your inequality follows.